# applyTransformation called twice with interpolatedTime == 1

Tags: android, animation

I have a `ListView` whose items need to be collapsed with an animation and then deleted. I use `Animation` for collapsing items, and after it's done collapsing I delete the item from the `ListView` (by deleting it from data list and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`). To detect if animation is done I check if `interpolatedTime` == 1.0 in `applyTransformation` method. The problem is that `applyTransformation` is called twice with `interpolatedTime' == 1, so I can't really rely on that (otherwise I can delete two items instead of just one). Why is this happening? Here's some of my code:

```
public static void collapseAndDelete(final View v, final ArrayList<AlarmClock> alarmClockArrayList,
                                     final AlarmsArrayAdapter adapter, final int position) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                alarmClockArrayList.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
                v.setAlpha(1.0f - interpolatedTime);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    a.setDuration(400);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and also solved it using `a.setAnimationListener(listener);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement animation listener to catch final callback

```
r.setAnimationListener(new OAnimationListener(this));
```

example of the class:

```
public class OAnimationListener implements AnimationListener{

    private MyView vv;


    public OAnimationListener(MyView vv) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.vv = vv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (vv != null)
            vv.stopAnim(2); //or any wanted callback

    }
}
```

do not forget to setup this:

```
r.setRepeatCount(0);

                r.setFillAfter(true);
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Although I would be interested to know why did I have my problem, is there any explanation?

Comment: @ulmaxy , i think it may appear, e.g., while using `r.setFillAfter(true);`. But I do not actially know. I have to see your full code. Futhermore, there are different callback implementations depend on vendor.